# How to identify the internet status in ionic3

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am using the following code to check the network status but it works only when the internet is made on or off similar like a switch but i would like to know the status of the internet when loading the page is itself.

```
this.network.onConnect().subscribe(data => {
    console.log('Net status', data.type)
    if (data.type === 'online') {
      this.commonService.hideloader();
      console.log('data is online');
      const path = 'driver_user/vendor_allocations/bulk_create_update.json';
      const params = {'vendor_allocations': [save]};
      this._tokenService.post(path, params).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
          res => {
            this.commonService.hideloader();
            console.log('res: ', res);
            this.sqliteService.update('entry', this.save_details, 'id', this.save_details.id).then(s => {
              console.log('Entry details saved in database', s);
              this.commonService.hideloader();
              this.commonService.presentToast('தகவல் சேமிக்கப்பட்டது');
              this.navCtrl.setRoot('FarmerlistPage');         
            });
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.commonService.hideloader();
          }
      );           
    } else if (data.type !== 'online') {
      console.log('user seems to be offline');
      this.commonService.hideloader();
      this.commonService.presentToast('தகவல் சேமிக்கப்பட்டது');
    }
  }, error => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new method and use the `network.type` property to check that:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home-page',
  templateUrl: 'home-page.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private platform: Platform, private network: Network, //...) {}

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      if(this.isOnline()) {
        // Code required to initialize the page if the user is online
      } else {
        // What to do when the user is offline
      }
    });
  }

  // Please notice that the type property will return one of the following 
  // connection types: `unknown`, `ethernet`, `wifi`, `2g`, `3g`, `4g`, 
  // `cellular`, `none`

  // Method that returns true if the user is connected to internet
  private isOnline(): boolean {
    return this.network.type.toLowerCase() !== 'none';
  }

  // Method that returns true if the user is not connected to internet
  private isOffline(): boolean {
    return this.network.type.toLowerCase() === 'none';
  }

}
```

Comment: I've added some more of the component code, let me know if that helps :)